# make komplex criteria filters in doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

got that query :

```
$criteria = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria();
        $criteria
            ->where($criteria->expr()->eq('collection', $post['id']))
            ->andWhere($criteria->expr()->eq('path', ''))
            ->orWhere($criteria->expr()->eq('path', '/'));
```

which does a query like

```
where collecion = 1 and path = '' or path = '/'
```

but how to say:

```
where collecion = 1 and (path = '' or path = '/')
```

cu n00n

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    $criteria = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria();
    $criteria
        ->where($criteria->expr()->eq('collection', $post['id']))
        ->andWhere(
            $criteria->expr()->orX(
                $criteria->expr()->eq('path', ''),
                $criteria->expr()->eq('path', '/')
            )

        );
```

Hope this help